# Can I bundle sqlalchemy's join() and where() statements to reuse them for a select and update query?

Tags: sqlalchemy

With sqlalchemy 1.4 I want to make an assertion on my data before changing it. These assertions and filter conditions span multiple tables. For updating I need the same joins and where clauses again. So currently I have something like:

```
query = session.query(func.sum(mytable.c.amount)).join().join().join().where().where().where()

sum_amount = session.execute(query).scalars().one()
assert sum_amount == 123, sum_amount

my_update = (
    mytable.update()
    .join()
    .join()
    .join()  
    .where() <-- same joins and conditions as above
    .where()
    .where()
    .values()
)
session.execute(my_update)
```

This does feel cluttered and could lead to easy human mistakes when one changes the select-part but not the update part. Can I bundle and reuse the join()s and where()s somehow?

Answer (score 0):

You could put them in a function that takes the statement as an argument and applies the operations, returning the updated statement:

A simple example:

```py
import sqlalchemy as sa


mytable = sa.table('t1', sa.column('id'), sa.column('foo'))
other_table = sa.table('t2', sa.column('id'), sa.column('mt_id'))

def f(stmt):
    if hasattr(stmt, 'join'):
        stmt = stmt.join(other_table, mytable.c.id == other_table.c.mt_id)
    stmt = stmt.where(mytable.c.foo == 'bar')
    return stmt


for stmt in [sa.select(mytable), sa.update(mytable)]:
    result = f(stmt)
    print(str(result))
    print()
```

Output:

```sql
SELECT t1.id, t1.foo 
FROM t1 JOIN t2 ON t1.id = t2.mt_id 
WHERE t1.foo = :foo_1

UPDATE t1 SET id=:id, foo=:foo WHERE t1.foo = :foo_1
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing this:

```
joins = my_table.join(other_table).join(third_table).join(and_so_on)
filters = [third_table.c.some_field == 1, ...]

# the select:
sum_amount = session.execute(
    select(my_table.c.amount)
    .select_from(joins)
    .where(*filters)
).scalars().one()

# the update:
ids = session.execute(
    select(my_table.c.id)
    .select_from(joins)
    .where(*base_filters)).scalars().all()

my_update = (
    my_table.update()
    .where(my_table.c.id.in_(ids))
    .values(status="foo", status_update="2023-11-22")
)
session.execute(query_update)
```

Constructing an update with `select_from()`+`join()` in the same way as the `select` is sadly not supported, hence the detour with the `in_`

What I learnt in the meantime is that a query's filter conditions are available as `my_query.whereclause`. But no such thing for the `joins`.